# Is it possible to use an std::string for read()?

Tags: c++, sockets, stdstring

Is it possible to use an std::string for read() ?

Example :

```
std::string data;

read(fd, data, 42);
```

Normaly, we have to use char* but is it possible to directly use a std::string ? (I prefer don't create a char* for store the result)

Thank's

Comment: If zero-copy is your goal, would it help you to replace "read" with "mmap", then wrap a fixed-allocated std::string around it?

Comment: Is there whitespace in the string you're reading?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, you'll need to create a `char*` somehow, since that's what the
function requires.  (BTW: you are talking about the Posix function
`read`, aren't you, and not `std::istream::read`?)  The problem isn't
the `char*`, it's what the `char*` points to (which I suspect is what
you actually meant).

The simplest and usual solution here would be to use a local array:

```
char buffer[43];
int len = read(fd, buffer, 42);
if ( len < 0 ) {
    //  read error...
} else if ( len == 0 ) {
    //  eof...
} else {
    std::string data(buffer, len);
}
```

If you want to capture directly into an `std::string`, however, this is
possible (although not necessarily a good idea):

```
std::string data;
data.resize( 42 );
int len = read( fd, &data[0], data.size() );
//  error handling as above...
data.resize( len );  //  If no error...
```

This avoids the copy, but quite frankly... The copy is insignificant
compared to the time necessary for the actual read and for the
allocation of the memory in the string.  This also has the (probably
negligible) disadvantage of the resulting string having an actual buffer
of 42 bytes (rounded up to whatever), rather than just the minimum
necessary for the characters actually read.

(And since people sometimes raise the issue, with regards to the
contiguity of the memory in `std:;string`: this was an issue ten or more
years ago.  The original specifications for `std::string` were designed
expressedly to allow non-contiguous implementations, along the lines of
the then popular `rope` class.  In practice, no implementor found this
to be useful, and people did start assuming contiguity.  At which point,
the standards committee decided to align the standard with existing
practice, and require contiguity.  So... no implementation has ever not
been contiguous, and no future implementation will forego contiguity,
given the requirements in C++11.)

Comment: "This avoids the copy, but quite frankly... The copy is insignificant compared to the time necessary for the actual read and for the allocation of the memory in the string." It depends on the size of the data being read. People invested quite a lot of effort into making the Linux kernel zero-copy on several data-transfer paths.

Comment: @user1202136 In this case, the size of the copy is 42 bytes.  And there is a dynamic allocation, and a transfer of bytes from the system.  The situation is different in the kernel, at least when dealing with things like buffers (which are likely on the order of 4KB or more, and are allocated from pools).

Comment: Since C++11, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at, using `&str[0]` is explicitly UB:  *For the first (non-const) version, the behavior is undefined if this character is modified to any value other than `CharT()`*.  And that's just for modifying that single character.  However, C++17 does add a non-const overload of [`.data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) which you could use after `.resize()`.  In practice you should be fine to use `&str[0]`, especially in C++11 and later where it's guaranteed that `&str[i] = str.data()+i`

Comment: @user1202136 what does Linux kernel have to do with this? The copy happens from the intermediate buffer that you yourself allocated, to the string. I've spent few hours today, trying to benchmark the `std::string::resize` with direct read and buffered read using `std::string::append` with buffer contents, and so far I found no answer which is better, but my flamegraph fluctuates on 1% difference between the two, and ironically enough, that margin is in favor of buffer + append just a bit more often with 8KiB buffer... Few MiB buffer is ~5% favor for resize, but what kind of IO is that fast?

Comment: @Sahsahae The Linux kernel is not directly related to the answer. Rather, I brought it as evidence that copying buffers can be expensive, and that engineers are willing to invest significant effort in avoiding needless copying. AFAIU, memory bandwidth becomes a bottleneck when you want to saturate the network card. A back-of-the-envelope calculation would look as follows: DDR5 tops 50GB/s, whereas network cards top ~10GB/s. So you can copy data at most 5 times. Notice that 50GB/s is likely in "burst mode", so in practice you get way less memory bandwidth than that. Anyway, copying matters. :)

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot and you should not. Usually, std::string implementations internally store other information such as the size of the allocated memory and the length of the actual string. C++ documentation explicitly states that modifying values returned by `c_str()` or `data()` results in undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

If the read function requires a char *, then no.  You could use the address of the first element of a std::vector of char as long as it's been resized first.  I don't think old (pre C++11) strings are guarenteed to have contiguous memory otherwise you could do something similar with the string.

Answer (score 0):

No, but

```
std::string data;
cin >> data;
```

works just fine.  If you really want the behaviour of `read(2)`, then you need to allocate and manage your own buffer of chars.

Comment: This will break on whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Because read() is intended for raw data input, std::string is actually a bad choice, because std::string handles text.  std::vector seems like the right choice to handle raw data.

Answer (score -1):

Using std::getline from the strings library - see [cplusplus.com](http://cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) - can read from an stream and write directly into a string object.  Example (again ripped from cplusplus.com - 1st hit on google for getline):

```
int main () {
  string str;
  cout << "Please enter full name: ";
  getline (cin,str);
  cout << "Thank you, " << str << ".\n";
}
```

So will work when reading from stdin (cin) and from a file (ifstream).

Comment: Why is this relevant? read is a system call on posix and is not related to console in.