# C++ Fork child, ask child for process list, kill a process in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, pipe, fork

I'm trying to create a child process, send the child process a command "LISTALL". The child process should then issue the system the command ps and return that list to the parent process. The parent process should then choose a process and kill it. This is what I have so far but I'm having trouble just getting it to run.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/wait.h>

char* getlistOfProcesses(const char* cmd) 
{
    FILE* pipe = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (!pipe) return (char*)"ERROR";
    char buffer[128];
    char *result = new char[1024];
    while(!feof(pipe)) {
        if(fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
            strcat(result, buffer);
    }
    pclose(pipe);
    return result;
}

int spawnGEdit()
{
    pid_t gPid = fork();
    if(gPid == 0)
    {
        execl("gedit", "gedit", NULL);
        exit(-1);
    }
    else
    {
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
    int P2C[2];
    int C2P[2];
    pipe(P2C);
    pipe(C2P);
    pid_t cPid = fork();
    char cmd[50];
    char* listOfProcesses = new char[1024];
    spawnGEdit();

    if (cPid == 0)
    {
        close(P2C[1]); 
        close(C2P[0]); 
        read(P2C[0], cmd, 10);
        if(strcmp(cmd,"LISTALL") == 0)
        {
            write(C2P[1], getlistOfProcesses("ps"), 1024);
            close(P2C[0]);
            close(C2P[1]);
        }
    }
    else if (cPid > 0)
    {
        close(C2P[1]); 
        close(P2C[0]); 
        write(P2C[1], "LISTALL", 10);
        wait(NULL);
        read(C2P[0], listOfProcesses,1024);
        printf("%s",listOfProcesses); 
        //TODO
        //get user input of a PID
        //kill the PID
        close(C2P[0]);
        close(P2C[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        // fork failed
        printf("Forking failed!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

These are the errors I'm getting when I try to compile it:

```
/tmp/cciTPIOZ.o: In function `getlistOfProcesses(char const*)':
test.cpp:(.text+0x53): undefined reference to `operator new[](unsigned long)'
/tmp/cciTPIOZ.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x166): undefined reference to `operator new[](unsigned long)'
/tmp/cciTPIOZ.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
test.cpp:(.text+0x2c0): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x2cf): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm compiling with with:

```
cc test.cpp -o test
```

Comment: I am a fan of popen().  So what problem are you having?  Does it compile? Does it hang? any output show?  You tried X, expected Y, and observed Z.  Describe X, Y, and Z

Comment: can you explain a bit more on what you mean by getting it to run ?

Comment: [If you look up the documentation for `popen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/popen.html), you'll notice it's declared as: `FILE *popen(const char *command, const char *mode)`. `command` is a `const char *`, but you've got a `std::string`. Those are not the same data types. Calling [`.c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) on your `cmd` might be what you need (though I think you've got more errors than just that one).

Comment: You say you're trying to do A, B, C, D, E and F, and that what you have written so far doesn't compile. **Try something simpler,** then build up.

Comment: In main() you do 2 forks, was that intentional?

Comment: Kam, do you mean 2 pipes? If so yes because I need each process to both read and write.

Comment: @ILikeToLearn 2 forks, the spawnGEdit and main both have fork commands

Comment: @Kam Yes, that was intentional. The GEdit fork is just to spawn the GEdit process. the other one is in order to spawn a child process. The parent process will then send the listall "command" and the child will respond with the list of all processes. I then have to kill one through the parent, I want to kill something I know so I spawned that other gEdit. Thanks for watching out though!

Comment: How is all the multiprocessing related to the linker errors? You should reduce your problems as much as possible before posting here, which includes removal of irrelevant parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compilation Errors occurred on line number:9,53,64 can be solved by using these:

line  9: `FILE* pipe = popen(cmd.data(), "r");`

line 53: `write(C2P[1], getlistOfProcesses("ps").data(), 1024);`

line 64: `printf("%s",listOfProcesses.data());`

Reason: These popen,write,printf requires char* as their arguments but you are passing them std::string. You have to use std::string.data() function instead as it returns pointer to the character array represented by `std::string` object.

And for your error on line 63, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105591/is-it-possible-to-use-an-stdstring-for-read).

### PS:- For your edits in question:

line 10: `if (!pipe) return (char*)"ERROR";`

line 12: `char *result = new char[1024];`

line 53: (change in line 7) `char* getlistOfProcesses(const char* cmd)`

A bit of advice: use `wait(NULL);` in parent process before reading `listOfProcesses` and `exit(0);` at the end of child process.

### Working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/wait.h>

char* getlistOfProcesses(const char* cmd) 
{
    FILE* pipe = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (!pipe) return (char*)"ERROR";
    char buffer[128];
    char *result = new char[1024];
    while(!feof(pipe)) {
        if(fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
            strcat(result, buffer);
    }
    pclose(pipe);
    return result;
}

int spawnGEdit()
{
    pid_t gPid = fork();
    if(gPid == 0)
    {
        execl("gedit", "gedit", NULL);
        exit(-1);
    }
    else
    {
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
    int P2C[2];
    int C2P[2];
    pipe(P2C);
    pipe(C2P);
    pid_t cPid = fork();
    char cmd[50];
    char* listOfProcesses = new char[1024];
    spawnGEdit();

    if (cPid == 0)
    {
        close(P2C[1]); 
        close(C2P[0]); 
        read(P2C[0], cmd, 10);
        if(strcmp(cmd,"LISTALL") == 0)
        {
            write(C2P[1], getlistOfProcesses("ps"), 1024);
            close(P2C[0]);
            close(C2P[1]);
        }
        exit(0);
    }
    else if (cPid > 0)
    {
        close(C2P[1]); 
        close(P2C[0]); 
        write(P2C[1], "LISTALL", 10);
        wait(NULL);
        read(C2P[0], listOfProcesses,1024);
        printf("%s",listOfProcesses); 
        //TODO
        //get user input of a PID
        //kill the PID
        close(C2P[0]);
        close(P2C[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        // fork failed
        printf("Forking failed!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I realized how stupid I was being at first, I did swap them to character arrays right now because I thought it would be easier, is there really any preference over which to use?

Comment: No, but when you are using some standard functions, then you have to choose according to the arguments required by them.

Comment: Well, changing things back to char* did the trick for the errors I think but it still doesn't compile, and thank you very much, that's good to know

Comment: Thank you, I see why I'm getting a lot of the errors still, It's hard to get used to everything needing to be cast and declared differently. Also thanks for the advice. I made the changes and even tries copy pasting what you wrote but it still doesn't seem to want to compile. I've updated the original post.